# Cascade delete using Fluent API

Tags: c#, entity-framework, cascading-deletes, ef-fluent-api

I have two entities. `Profile` and `ProfileImages`. After fetching a `Profile` I want to delete `ProfileImages` through `Profile` without it just removing the reference to `Profile` (setting it to `null`). How can this be done with fluent API and Cascading Delete? Do I set the `HasRequired` attribute or the `CascadeDelete` attribute?

```
public class Profile 
{
    //other code here for entity
    public virtual ICollection<ProfileImage> ProfileImages { get; set; }
}

public class ProfileImage 
{
    // other code here left out        
    [Index]
    public string ProfileRefId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ProfileRefId")]
    public virtual Profile Profile { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add this to your `DB Context`:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Profile>()
    .HasOptional(c => c.ProfileImages)
    .WithOptionalDependent()
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
}
```

Read more here:[`Enabling Cascade Delete`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591620.aspx#CascadeDelete)

> You can configure cascade delete on a relationship by using the
>   WillCascadeOnDelete method. If a foreign key on the dependent entity
>   is not nullable, then Code First sets cascade delete on the
>   relationship. If a foreign key on the dependent entity is nullable,
>   Code First does not set cascade delete on the relationship, and when
>   the principal is deleted the foreign key will be set to null.